How can we define a linear form on semidirect product of lie algebras?
Given a lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ as direct product $\mathfrak{g}=\mathfrak{h}\rtimes \mathfrak{n}$,  how can we define a linear form on $\mathfrak{g}$ ?
Must we use only the sum of the linear forms on each compenent of $\mathfrak{g}$
Remark: I found this part in the litterature, and I have been confused:

Can someone help?
